# Angular2 variable in html binding

Tags: angular, data-binding, ionic2

So I want to display a html string in my template. To do this I use this in my html file:

```
<div [innerHTML]="myObject.string | safeHtml"></div>
```

Where `safeHtml` is a pipe to mark the html string as trusted, like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089093/3050534) for example. This is my **component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: "my html file"
})
export class MyComponent {
    myObject;
    variable;

    constructor() {
        this.variable = "hello";
        this.myObject = {string: "text text <b [innerHTML]='variable | safeHtml'></b> text text" };
    }
}
```

Right now this is displayed in the `<div>`: `text text text text`. When I inspect this in my browser, there is an `<b>` tag also where it should be, but it's empty, like: `<b [innerHTML]="variable | safeHtml"></b>`.

I don't want to do something like this where `myObject.string` is:

```
"text text <b>" + this.variable + "</b>text text"
```

That's because `myObject` actually is in another component and it doesn't has a link to `this.variable` (I don't know if that's good practise).

Can anyone help me with this to display the variable within a html string? I hope I explained it good enough.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the `myString` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @Sampath, the content of `myString` is in my question, currently it's: `"text text <b [innerHtml]='variable | safeHtml'></b> text text"`

Comment: Can you show your `JSON object`?

Comment: sorry for off topic, but may i know what is `safeHtml` here ?

Comment: @Sampath, it's like: `this.object = { string: "text text .. " }`, it really is nothing special. And everything is working fine, except for the `variable`, which is empty.

@PardeepJain, in my question I linked to a post where it's explained: [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding/41089093#41089093)

Comment: What is `variable` then?

Comment: @Sampath, currently nothing more than `this.variable = "hello"`. I'm sorry if I'm not explaining well.

Comment: I think you'll need to show the component code fully so we can see how you've set up the template code and the properties of the component.ts

Comment: Why are you changing the innerHtml of the `<b>` tag? You're outputting the HTML from code, so why not just interpolate the string you want inside the `<b>SomeStringHere</b>` tags?